# Control is not found in FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, flowlayoutpanel

I have many group Boxes in a flow layout panel all are generated programmaticaly. when I try to find any specific groupbox at run time  nothing comes out. Here is my code, Please help.

```
    foreach (Control ctr in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
    {
        if (ctr.Name=="BSE")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Control is found");                     
        }                
    }
```

Code, which creates controls:

```
var Allzone = (from a in db.Zones select a.name).ToList();
foreach (var z in Allzone)
{ 
    GroupBox g = new GroupBox(); 
    g.Text = z; 
    g.Name = z; 
    g.Tag = z; 
    g.Font = new Font("Verdana", 8,FontStyle.Bold); 
    g.ForeColor = Color.White; 
    g.Width = 49; 
    g.Height = 90; 
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(g); 
}
```

Comment: Show the code that creates the controls and assigns them to `flowLayoutPanel1`.

Comment: >var Allzone = (from a in db.Zones select a.name).ToList();
>            foreach (var z in Allzone)
>            {
>                GroupBox g = new GroupBox();
>                g.Text = z;
>                g.Name = z;
>                g.Tag = z;
>                g.Font = new Font("Verdana", 8,FontStyle.Bold);
>                g.ForeColor = Color.White;
>                g.Width = 49;
>                g.Height = 90;
>              flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(g);
>            }

Comment: What is `Allzone` and what does it contain?

Comment: AllZone contain the name of all zone But this is not a problem Because All Control generated perfectly!
the only problem i m facing is how to find a control in flow panel

Comment: C# is case-sensitive, so if the name you assigned was `bse` and you test for `BSE` that will not equate.

Comment: "i also try this nothing happens"  if (ctr.Name.ToUpper() == "BSE".ToUpper())

Comment: I just setup a test that works.  In place of `Allzone` I used a `String[]` (since I don't know what yours _really_ is).  Otherwise, my code is identical to yours.  I suspect there is more going on here, or `Allzones` is not simply a collection of `String` objects.

Comment: I got it just add trim() in control name..Now the working Code is

foreach (Control ctr in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls) { if (ctr.Name.Trim()=="BSE") { MessageBox.Show("Control is found"); 
} 
}

this Trim() Ruined my all day.Thanks DonBotinott

Comment: Do the Trim() and ToUpper() when you set the Name property: `g.Name = z.Trim().ToUpper();`  Then your check should behave better without needing all the extra stuff...

Answer (score 0):

I got it just add trim() in control name.

Now the working Code is

```
 foreach (Control ctr in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls) 
{ 

if (ctr.Name.Trim()=="BSE") 

   {
     MessageBox.Show("Control is found");
   } 
}
```

this Trim() Ruined my all day.
Thanks DonBotinott